# Chrome extension tabs onUpdated event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension that should get notified every time a new tab has opened and load page, and for that purpose I'am using chrome.tabs.onUpdated event.

The problem is that in case an iframe is inserted on that page/tab that is hosted on some domain(has src), onUpdated event is trigered. Is there a way to differentiate these events for "real" tab load from those triggered for iframe load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tabs.onUpdated` triggers when state changes between `loading` to `complete`. Presumably, inserting an iframe puts the tab to `loading` state again.

You could see if `details.url` is defined in `onUpdated` listener - if not, you know that the document's URL did not change.

Perhaps you should use [`webNavigation` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) instead for your purpose. There, you get a `TransitionQualifier` that you can use to filter out subframe navigation.

Comment: I don't see how I could use TransitionQualifier to distinct regular navigations from those made by iframes(maybe I'am missing something), but TransitionType has "auto_subframe" value for those cases when child frame triggers navigation automatically, without user interaction, that could solve this problem. Maybe you had this in mind. Anyhow, thank you!

Comment: As of Chrome 74, `parentFrameId` - The ID of the parent frame, or -1 if this is the main frame.

Answer (score 5):

This question helped me with my extension, recognizing the difference between a new page and loading content on the same page, so thought I'd share my solution. First you need to call `onUpdated` in background.js:

#### Manifest

```
{
  "name": "My test extension",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

#### background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
  function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // read changeInfo data
    if (changeInfo.url) {
      // url has changed; do something here

    }
  }
);
```

Then you can expand that script to send message data from background.js to your content script (using [chrome.runtime.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-sendMessage)):

#### background.js (con't)

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
  function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // read changeInfo data
    if (changeInfo.url) {
      // url has changed; do something here
      // like send message to content script
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage( tabId, {
        message: 'hello!',
        url: changeInfo.url
      })
    }
  }
);
```

And finally listen for that data in your extension's content script to be used however:

#### contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    // listen for messages sent from background.js
    if (request.message === 'hello!') {
      console.log(request.url) // new url is now in content scripts!
    }
});
```

You can pass whatever data you'd like from `background.js`. Hope that helps someone! \ (•◡•) /